# What function does ことをする serve here?

Tags: interpretation

In ran into this sentence

> 「ベレト君は気に食わないこと全部に悪いことをしてました」

but I'm having a hard time making sense of it. I get that the first part means that "the stuff Beret finds distasteful".
But I'm not sure how to fit that in the remaining which I'd reckon means "completely" and "did bad things".

It seems like there is a missing connective or two. Did the author make typo here or is this usage a sense of ことをする I'm unaware?

Here's more context but I'm not if I'll help:

> 「噂ってありもしないことが大袈裟に広まったりするでしょ。多分それ」
> （本当は違います。ベレト君は気に食わないこと全部に悪いことをしてました）

Comment: [This](https://kakuyomu.jp/works/16816700428207099828/episodes/16816700429482799535) appears to be the full context, it may help people to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically nothing is missing in the sentence. It is

- ペレト君は (Subject)
- 気に食わないこと全部に (Indirect object)
- 悪いことを (Object)
- してました (Verb)

You may be mis-parsing 気に食わないこと全部に, which means *to  all the things he doesn't like*.

全... takes this pattern as in

- ワールドカップを見た人全員 All the people who saw World Cup;
- 今まで読んだ本全部 All the books I ever read.

Thus the sentence means *Pereto did bad things to all the things he found distasteful*.

I suppose it means "he behaved badly (towards his servant?) each time he found something distasteful" (as far as I browsed the beginning chapter). The phrasing of the sentence is actually a little strange in the sense that it does not really sound *he got nasty towards one particular person*.

Comment: So 悪いことをする means do bad things towards the indirect object? Is there another example of this usage?

Comment: Just to be clear. Does  悪いことをする mean "turn things bad" or "act in bad manner towards" or " do badly"? I'm asking this usage of する is pretty new to me.

Comment: Let me see if I got this: Aに悪いことをする means that the subject/actor does bad things towards A since A is marked by に. Is  this correct?

Comment: @hyorogan For the 1st and 3rd comments, you are right. For the 2nd, it is literally 'do bad things' or maybe in this case 'do evil things'.

Comment: More ordinary usage of Aに悪いことをする means "I'm sorry for what I did to A", which shouldn't be the case in question.

Comment: So, back to the question, it just means *Pereto did bad things to all the things he found distasteful.* I didn't read the whole passage up to there, so could be wrong, but the rumor seems to refer to 'him' being nasty to シア.

Comment: Anyway, it is admitting the negative rumors about him are actually true. The preceding sentences say the rumors are exaggerated and then in brackets the character says 'it is a lie'.